# Expo Ios Build Archieve Failed And Simulator Build Successfull

Tags: iphone, build, expo

› Executing ElectricWeb » Bundle React Native code and images
Bundler cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute)

❌  error: File /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ElectricWeb-dxhammxcxpudvmflxlgofhygnywo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ElectricWeb/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/ElectricWeb.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues

▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ElectricWeb-dxhammxcxpudvmflxlgofhygnywo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ElectricWeb/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/ElectricWeb.build/Release-iphoneos/ElectricWeb.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'ElectricWeb' from project 'ElectricWeb')
▸ (1 failure)

Please give me this error solution as soon as possible I am not able to update my Ios Application
SDK version 49
Xcode Version 15.0.1@latest